How to solve ERROR: ResolutionImpossible when packaging a python program into an exe file using setuptools
I wrote a Python game using Panda3d and then built an exe file according to the steps in the official documentation
My setup.py is written like this:
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="四子棋",
    version="1.0",
    author="",
    description="一个3D四子棋游戏",
    options={
        'build_apps': {
            'include_patterns': [
                'assets/*',
                'models/*',
            ],
            'gui_apps': {
                'your_app': '四子棋.py',
            },
            'platforms': ['win_amd64'],
            'log_filename': '日志文件.log',
            'log_append': True,
            'plugins': ['pandagl', 'p3openal_audio',"p3ffmpeg","p3ptloader","p3assimp"],
            "icons": ["assets\icon.ico"]
        }
    },
    install_requires=['lxml','markdown','customtkinter','bs4','pillow','panda3d','panda3d-gltf','spark_ai_python'],
)

And my requirements. txt is written like this:
lxml
Markdown
customtkinter
bs4
pillow
Panda3D
panda3d-gltf
spark_ai_python

The problem should be with the spark_ai_python library. The following is the error message from the console:
ERROR: Cannot install llama-index-vector-stores-chroma because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    chromadb 0.4.24 depends on pypika>=0.48.9
    chromadb 0.4.23 depends on pypika>=0.48.9
    chromadb 0.4.22 depends on pypika>=0.48.9

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip to attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

I tried to use the pyinstaller packaging program, and although it can open the window after compilation, it shows that the font cannot be loaded.
Please provide a solution in the comments section, experts
Thanks a lot!
